# How to add a unique tag to each log in logging.properties

Tags: java, logging, tomcat8, java.util.logging

My standard configuration of Tomcat 8.5 splits the logs into

- Catalina,
- manager,
- localhost ,
- host-manager

**My task is to add to each file unique tags**:
CatalinaTag, mngTag, localTag, hostMngTag

I tried to find a solution on the internet but without any success.

My propse of logging.properties look like this:

```
handlers = 1catalina.mypackage.CatalinaConsoleHandler, 2localhost.mypackage.LocalhostConsoleHandler, 3manager.mypackage.ManagerConsoleHandler, 4host-manager.mypackage.LocalhostConsoleHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.handlers = 1catalina.mypackage.CatalinaConsoleHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

1catalina.mypackage.CatalinaConsoleHandler.directory = /.../logs
1catalina.mypackage.CatalinaConsoleHandler.prefix = catalina.
1catalina.mypackage.CatalinaConsoleHandler.formatter = mypackage.CatalinaFormatter
mypackage.CatalinaFormatter.format = [CatalinaTag %1$tF %1$tT] [%4$-7s] %5$s %n

2localhost.mypackage.LocalhostConsoleHandler.directory = /.../logs
2localhost.mypackage.LocalhostConsoleHandler.prefix = localhost.
2localhost.mypackage.LocalhostConsoleHandler.formatter =mypackage.LocalhostFormatter
mypackage.LocalhostFormatter.format = [localhostTag %1$tF %1$tT] [%4$-7s] %5$s %n

3manager.mypackage.ManagerConsoleHandler.directory = /.../logs
3manager.mypackage.ManagerConsoleHandler.prefix = manager.
3manager.mypackage.ManagerConsoleHandler.formatter =mypackage.ManagerFormatter
mypackage.ManagerFormatter.format = [manager %1$tF %1$tT] [%4$-7s] %5$s %n

4host-manager.mypackage.LocalhostConsoleHandler.directory = /.../logs
4host-manager.mypackage.LocalhostConsoleHandler.prefix = host-manager.
4host-manager.mypackage.LocalhostConsoleHandler.formatter =mypackage.HostManagerFormatter
mypackage.HostManagerFormatter.format = [manager %1$tF %1$tT] [%4$-7s] %5$s %n

############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.mypackage.LocalhostConsoleHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = 3manager.mypackage.ManagerConsoleHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].handlers = 4host-manager.mypackage.LocalhostConsoleHandler
```

Here is an example of *ConsoleHandler

```
package mypackage;

import java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler;

public class CatalinaConsoleHandler extends ConsoleHandler {
}
```

Here an example of *Formatter

```
package mypackage;

import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;

public class CatalinaFormatter extends SimpleFormatter {
}
```

But so far I am not able to do it. Do you have any idea why?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Can you post the code for your current solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were using the original `java.util.logging`, your approach of subclassing `ConsoleHandler` (or rather `FileHandler`) and `SimpleFormatter` multiple times would be the correct one: JUL allows only one instance of every `Handler` and `Formatter` class. This approach **will** work, but you need to add `mypackage.CatalinaConsoleHandler` and company to the *system* classloader (cf. Tomcat classloaders).

However there is a much easier approach: Tomcat has its own extensions to JUL (cf. [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/logging.html#Using_java.util.logging_(default))), which allow you to:

- add a prefix to each handler name and create multiple handlers of the same class. The prefix must start with a digit (e.g. `1catalina.`). Prefixed properties apply only to the specific handler, while non-prefixed properties apply to all handlers.
- use property placeholders `${...}` which will be replaced with the appropriate Java system property. There are also three special properties (`classloader.serverName`, `classloader.hostName` and `classloader.webappName`) that resolve the name of the engine, host and context respectively.

Therefore you can use:

```
# List of all handler names:
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler
# Handlers attached to the root logger:
.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

# These properties apply to all handlers
org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

# These properties apply only to `1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler`
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = catalina.
1catalina.java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format = [CatalinaTag %1$tF %1$tT] [%4$-7s] %5$s %n

# These properties apply only to `2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler`
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = localhost.
2localhost.java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format = [LocalhostTag %1$tF %1$tT] [%4$-7s] %5$s %n
```

Comment: It is exactly what I looking for :) Thx!